# Install JRE on an AWS EC2 Windows Instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jvm

I have a 3rd party application for WINDOWS that was written in java, so it requires a JRE installed on the machine.

I want to create an AWS EC2 Windows Instance and install JRE so I will be able to run the exe file as in my local computer.

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on your 3rd party application; we can't answer as written. Also, *java for windows* doesn't normally create exe file(s). So your question is **very** confusing.

Comment: Yes it is possible but your question is too vague to give a precise answer.  Please describe your problem precisely first.

Comment: Hello Elliott and Sebastien, thanks for your comments, I've edited the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Modern day you have three ways to do this.

1. You can create an AMI with AWS ImageBuilder that pre-installs JRE on the image before you use it. This is better when you are going to use the image for scaling as then it does not need to download and install the JRE before being ready to use.
2. Create a RunDocument that is executed when the instance starts via a userdata script.
3. Install chocolately and then java through the AWS EC2 userdata script

:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

choco install openjdk8 -y
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add inbound and outbound rules for HTTP and HTTPS
2. Reboot your Windows instance
3. Open explorer in your instance, and install Java manually from the Java official page
4. Once you install the JRE, go to "Environment variables" and add the path where `Java.exe` resides to your 'Path' variable

You are good to go!